# Android Studio - DDMS does not update File Explorer's view

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

I have my AVD emulator running in Android Studio, and want to store a file on the emulated device.

Using the push and pull buttons does not seem to store the device, while the console is not reporting any errors. Just dragging the file into the /mnt/sdcard folder or root or any other folder does not seem to store the file either, even though I get a popup window saying that it is transferring.

Is there a way to refresh the File Explorer in DDMS? Or does anyone know why my files might not be transferring to the emulated device?

Answer (score 3):

You can force refresh by killing and restarting the Android Debug Bridge process.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: It seems like a comment instead of an answer. Please add some points, bit more explanation not just a code.

Comment: `adb reconnect` seems to work to restart the Device File Explorer connection to an emulator when `adb start-server` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Reselecting the same device in the Device File Explorer also seems to do the trick!
[Android Studio Dolphin Device File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcTXL.png)